# Shapeless example with map won't compile (scala)

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm trying to map over an HList in shapeless.  The following example is derived from [here](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview%3a-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-lists):

```
import shapeless._
import poly._

object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]) = {

        object choose extends (Set ~> Option) {
          def apply[T](s : Set[T]) = s.headOption
        }

        val sets = Set(1) :: Set("foo") :: HNil

        val opts = sets map choose   // map selects cases of choose for each HList element
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I am unable to compile the example.  The compiler says "value map is not a member of HCons[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int],HCons[scala.collection.immutable.Set[String],HNil]]".  I suspect there is a missing import of an implicit that defines the map operation on HLists, but I don't know what that import should be.  I'm using sbt with the following build.sbt file:

```
name := "scala-polymorphism-experiments"

version := "0.1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Sonatype OSS Releases"  at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/",
  "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.0" % "test",
                            "com.chuusai" % "shapeless" % "2.0.0-SNAPSHOT" cross CrossVersion.full changing())
```

I also have this problem if I use the M1 release of 2.0.0.  What should I change to make this example compile and run?

Comment: [Works for me](http://pastebin.com/1DX04XpG). What is your `sbt` version?

Comment: Tested on sbt `0.12.1`, `0.12.4`, `0.13.0` and `0.13.1`. Are you sure the problem is in this code sample?

Comment: @senia Wow, thanks for testing.  It now works for me, too.  I tried commenting out all code in all other files in the project, and that fixed it.  The weird thing is that when I then uncommented that same code and compiled again, the example still worked.  So, I don't really know what the problem was.  Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: `sbt clean` to the rescue.

Comment: @jcrudy What do you think about answering your own question and approve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was never determined.  The solution was to comment out all code in all other scala files in the project, recompile, then uncomment and compile again.  No doubt an

```
sbt clean
```

would have done just as well.